# How do I add a dynamic list of parameters to a parametrized fixture using another fixture? (pytest)

Tags: python, pytest

I'm not sure if this is possible - there are quite a few variants of this question, but nothing I've found exactly addresses this case. I've considered using pytest-lazy-fixture as per this:

https://miguendes.me/how-to-use-fixtures-as-arguments-in-pytestmarkparametrize

...but it doesn't apply for replacing the whole list. The below is not valid syntax, but I think it conveys the idea.

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def list_of_item() -> List[int]:
    return [1,2,3]

@pytest.fixture(params=list_of_item)
def item(request) -> int:
    return request.param
```

Thanks!

UPDATE: Following comments, I thought I should elaborate on the motivation for this - I need to use a command line argument to re-generate the list, hence the need for the list of parameters to be from a fixture

Comment: I think I'm starting to learn why this might be impossible - since the number of tests is determined prior to gathering fixtures, having a dynamic list length from fixtures doesn't work. You can make one element of the list dynamic, because this only effects the execution of the test and not the gathering.

Comment: I think that your question is not exactly clear. _"I think it conveys the idea"_ - if I were to make a suggestion based on your example I'd tell you not to make `list_of_item` a fixture but keep it a plain function and then use `@pytest.fixture(params=list_of_item())` in declaration of `item` but something tells me that this is not gonna be useful for you because of some requirements that you haven't described.

Comment: Ok you make a good point - I'll add some more restrictions